# How to programatically use GroupBy and GroupView in windows folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have lot of folders in windows. In each of the folder there are Image/Videos/Excel/Word/PS/Cad..etc.

Im accessing each file programatically, but when I select the folder each time I tend to manually selecting `GroupBy="Date Access"`, `GroupView="Details"`, add a `column="date modified"`. I cant find a way of saving a customized folder settings in my folders.

Is it possible in c#? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: What did you try so far? Provide some code please.

Comment: @msd. i dont have a code for that because i dont have an idea how to do it or its even possible. My codes are for accessing propertyItems of the files and its irrelevant to my question.

Comment: you can apply the current view to all folders https://superuser.com/questions/861456/how-to-customize-columns-in-windows-explorer-as-default-settings

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in C# to group files by `date-accessed` or `date-modified`.
In following example I'll show you how to group using year of `creation-date`.

First you need to get file infos:

```
// get file-infos for all files in D:\Daten
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Daten");

// and convert them to file-info-objects
List<FileInfo> filesWithFileInfo = files.Select(it => new FileInfo(it)).ToList();
```

Then you can use `GroupBy` of Linq to group them by year of create date:

```
List<IGrouping<int, FileInfo>> filesGroupedByYear = filesWithFileInfo.GroupBy(it => it.CreationTime.Year).ToList();
```

And this enumerates over all groups and then over files in every group:

```
foreach(IGrouping<int,FileInfo> filesOfOneYear in filesGroupedByYear)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{filesOfOneYear.Count()} Files of year {filesOfOneYear.Key}:");
  foreach(FileInfo file in filesOfOneYear.ToList())
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{file.Name}");
  }
}
```